# How can I test binary file uploading with django-rest-framework's test client?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-unittest

I have a Django application with a view that accepts a file to be uploaded. Using the Django REST framework I'm subclassing APIView and implementing the post() method like this:

```
class FileUpload(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            image = request.FILES['image']
            # Image processing here.
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except KeyError:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data={'detail' : 'Expected image.'})
```

Now I'm trying to write a couple of unittests to ensure authentication is required and that an uploaded file is actually processed.

```
class TestFileUpload(APITestCase):
    def test_that_authentication_is_required(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.client.post('my_url').status_code, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    def test_file_is_accepted(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)
        image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))
        tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg')
        image.save(tmp_file)
        with open(tmp_file.name, 'rb') as data:
            response = self.client.post('my_url', {'image': data}, format='multipart')
            self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)
```

But this fails when the REST framework attempts to encode the request

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 104, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s, encoding, errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 118: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/webapp/myproject/myapp/tests.py", line 31, in test_that_jpeg_image_is_accepted
    response = self.client.post('my_url', { 'image': data}, format='multipart')
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.3/site-    packages/rest_framework/test.py", line 76, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.3/site-packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 470, in generic
    data = force_bytes_or_smart_bytes(data, settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 73, in smart_text
    return force_text(s, encoding, strings_only, errors)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 116, in force_text
    raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)
django.utils.encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 118: invalid start byte. You passed in b'--BoUnDaRyStRiNg\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="tmpyz2wac.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff[binary data omitted]' (<class 'bytes'>)
```

How can I make the test client send the data without attempting to decode it as UTF-8?

Comment: Pass `{ 'image': file}` instead

Comment: @arocks Eagle eyes! I've corrected the typo in the posting, the actual code did not have this problem.

Comment: Your code work for me. Thank you!

Comment: It was because I was missing format='multipart' - doh

Comment: where is tempfile coming from?

Answer (score 60):

When testing file uploads, **you should pass the stream object into the request, not the data**.

This was pointed out in the comments by [@arocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3107299/arocks)

> Pass { 'image': file} instead

But that didn't full explain why it was needed (and also didn't match the question). For this specific question, you should be doing

```
from PIL import Image

class TestFileUpload(APITestCase):

    def test_file_is_accepted(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)

        image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))

        tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg')
        image.save(tmp_file)
        tmp_file.seek(0)

        response = self.client.post('my_url', {'image': tmp_file}, format='multipart')

       self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)
```

This will match a standard Django request, where the file is passed in as a stream object, and Django REST Framework handles it. When you just pass in the file data, Django and Django REST Framework interpret it as a string, which causes issues because it is expecting a stream.

And for those coming here looking to another common error, why file uploads just won't work but normal form data will: **make sure to set `format="multipart"` when creating the request**.

This also gives a similar issue, and was pointed out by [@RobinElvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285549/robin-elvin) in the comments

> It was because I was missing format='multipart'

Comment: For some reason this leads me to 400 error. The error returned is {"file":["The submitted file is empty."]}.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to allocate a tempfile for whatever reason (perf would be one), you can also do `tmp_file = BytesIO(b'some text')`; this will give you a binary stream that can be passed as a file object.  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).

Comment: Had to add `tmp_file.seek(0)` before the `post`, but otherwise perfect! This almost drove me nuts so thanks!

Comment: where's the `Image` module coming from?

Comment: @RudolfOlah `Image` comes from the Pillow library. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Comment: It is important to pay attention that it is `format=multipart` and not `content-type`. I will leave this here if someone is also making the same mistake and getting a  `415`

Answer (score 22):

Python 3 users: make sure you `open` the file in `mode='rb'` (read,binary). Otherwise, when Django calls `read` on the file the `utf-8` codec will immediately start choking. The file should be decoded as binary not utf-8, ascii or any other encoding.

```
# This won't work in Python 3
with open(tmp_file.name) as fp:
        response = self.client.post('my_url', 
                                   {'image': fp}, 
                                   format='multipart')

# Set the mode to binary and read so it can be decoded as binary
with open(tmp_file.name, 'rb') as fp:
        response = self.client.post('my_url', 
                                   {'image': fp}, 
                                   format='multipart')
```

Comment: I think that `{'image': data}` ought to be `{'image': fp}` in the answer.  I was struggling with uploads until I found this post, yet my tests did not pass until I put  the file handle object `fp` in place of `data` in the `{'image': data}` dictionary described above. (`{'image': fp}` worked in my case, `{'image': data}` did not.)

Comment: Updated. Thanks DMfll.

Answer (score 14):

You can use  **Django built-in** [`SimpleUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/):

```py
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

class TestFileUpload(APITestCase):
    ...

    def test_file_is_accepted(self):
        ...

       tmp_file = SimpleUploadedFile(
                      "file.jpg", "file_content", content_type="image/jpg")

       response = self.client.post(
                      'my_url', {'image': tmp_file}, format='multipart')
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not so simple to understand how to do it if you want to use the PATCH method, but I found the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15153048/5157209).

```
from django.test.client import BOUNDARY, MULTIPART_CONTENT, encode_multipart

with open(tmp_file.name, 'rb') as fp:
    response = self.client.patch(
        'my_url', 
        encode_multipart(BOUNDARY, {'image': fp}), 
        content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

For those in Windows, the answer is a bit different. I had to do the following:

```
resp = None
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg', delete=False) as tmp_file:
    image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), "#ddd")
    image.save(tmp_file, format="JPEG")
    tmp_file.close()

# create status update
with open(tmp_file.name, 'rb') as photo:
    resp = self.client.post('/api/articles/', {'title': 'title',
                                               'content': 'content',
                                               'photo': photo,
                                               }, format='multipart')
os.remove(tmp_file.name)
```

The difference, as pointed in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212515/72350), the file cannot be used after it was closed in Windows.  Under Linux, @Meistro's answer should work.

Comment: On OSX10.12.5 I got `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

Comment: I don't think you need the `tmp_file.close()` with the `with` statement.