# how to post an image file in the django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-unittest

i am doing unit tests on my rest framework API, my model:

```
class attach():
    attachment = models.ImageField
    name = models.CharField
```

then i attempt to post to is via the API i defined(standard serializer not shown here)

```
c = Client()
with open('wishlist.doc') as fp:
     c.post('/customers/wishes/', {'name': 'fred', 'attachment': fp}, format='multipart')
```

i get the following stack trace

```
ValueError: The 'attachment' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

how do i associate the key attachment with the file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `format="multipart"` when creating the request.

```
[...]
c.post('/customers/wishes/', {'name': 'fred', 'attachment': fp}, format='multipart')
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27576436/1682844