# How to test file upload in Django rest framework using PUT?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest-django

I would like to write a unit test for a view on a Django REST Framework application. The test should upload a file using PUT, in essence equivalent to

> http -a malkarouri PUT http://localhost:8000/data-packages/upload/ka @tmp/hello.py

The code I have written so far is

```
factory = APIRequestFactory()
request = factory.put(                                                                                                                                                                '/data-packages/upload/ka',
    data,
    content_type='application/octet-stream',
    content_disposition="attachment; filename=data.dump")
force_authenticate(request, user)
view = PackageView.as_view()
response = view(request, "k.py")
```

which, obviously, does not upload a file. The specific error when running the test is 400:

> {u'detail': u'Missing filename. Request should include a Content-Disposition header with a filename parameter.'}

Notably, I am using a request factory to test the view rather than a full client. That is what makes solutions such as the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201676/how-can-i-test-binary-file-uploading-with-django-rest-frameworks-test-client) not work for me.

What is the correct way to set the content disposition header?

Answer (score 10):

Hi you need to use the SimpleUploadedFile wrapper for that :

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.core.files import File

data = File(open('path/bond-data.dump', 'rb'))
upload_file = SimpleUploadedFile('data.dump', data.read(),content_type='multipart/form-data')
request = factory.put( '/data-packages/upload/ka',
   {'file':upload_file,other_params},
    content_type='application/octet-stream',
    content_disposition="attachment; filename=data.dump")
```

Ps : I am using `APITestCase`

Comment: I am afraid it didn't work for me. The PUT is designed to accept a file directly, not a form with a file parameter. Would that be the problem?

Comment: it's not a problem, this is not a form wrapper, this is a file wrapper and add all the headers needed for being handled in django. At least i use it this way for testing the upload of documents on our website.

Comment: For me, I had to remove the argument content_type='application/octet-stream' and instead had to add format='multipart' factory.put in order to get it running.

Comment: good answer, but it would be nice if the file path used `os.join` or something else to find the file, maybe from the Django static or uploads folders.

Answer (score 7):

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.test import TestCase

from rest_framework.test import APIClient


class MyTest(TestCase):
    client_class = APIClient

    def test_it(self):
        file = SimpleUploadedFile("file.txt", b"abc", content_type="text/plain")
        payload = {"file": file}
        response = self.client.post("/some/api/path/", payload, format="multipart")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)

        # If you do more calls in this method with the same file then seek to zero
        file.seek(0)
```

Comment: This seems like a POST call rather than a PUT. No?