# DRF APITestCase not use `multipart` with other param

Tags: python, django, rest

I have 2 models. First is `House`. Second is `HouseImage`
Therefore I have to submit the image with `ForeigneKey`
I can upload by using the REST normally, but failed to do unittest.
The reason why I keep doing unittest in here because I have a more specifications waiting for me and I would not do hand-test for sure.

`django==1.11.5`
`djangorestframework==3.6.4`
`python3.6.2`
`PostgreSQL 9.6.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit`

Here is my additional source code.
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/a013be9c3b7ab5f0cc130e320b19da4b

import tempfile

```
from PIL import Image
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from model_mommy import mommy
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient

from soken_web.apps.houses.models import House


class HouseImageTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = mommy.make(User, username='Pan')
        self.house = mommy.make(House, location="100.00, 100.00")

    def test_post_image(self):
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

        image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))

        tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg')
        image.save(tmp_file)
        data = {
            'image': tmp_file,
            'house': self.house.id,
        }

        response = self.client.post(reverse('api:house_images-list'), data, format='multipart')

        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)
```

**Problem:**
Server raises `appliation/json` type to me

**Attempts:**
1. Replace `format=multipart` with `content_type/multipart`. Same error
1. User both `format=mulipart` and `content_type/multipart`. It is not permitted by DRF

**Solution:**
@zaidfazil Thank you very much. You are right. I have to use real-file

```
import tempfile

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from model_mommy import mommy
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient

from soken_web.apps.houses.models import House


class HouseImageTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = mommy.make(User, username='Pan')
        self.house = mommy.make(House, location="100.00, 100.00")
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    def test_post_image(self):
        file = File(open('static/rest_framework/img/grid.png', 'rb'))
        uploaded_file = SimpleUploadedFile('new_image.jpg', file.read(), content_type='multipart/form-data')
        data = {
            'image': uploaded_file,
            'houses': self.house.id,
        }

        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api:house_images-list'), data, format='multipart')
        response.render()

        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)
```

**References:**
[How can I test binary file uploading with django-rest-framework's test client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201676/how-can-i-test-binary-file-uploading-with-django-rest-frameworks-test-client)
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: Did you try the solution from other answers that you link on references? Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30291143/4900574 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43212184/4900574

Comment: Thank you for your response. First URL I got I/O error. The next one was interrupt by zaidfazil answer and finally solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to convert the file into uploaded file format before posting to the url,

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.core.files import File

class HouseImageTest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = mommy.make(User, username='Pan')
        self.house = mommy.make(House, location="100.00, 100.00")
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    def test_post_image(self):

        image = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100))    
        tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg')
        image.save(tmp_file)

        file = File(tmp_file)
        uploaded_file = SimpleUploadedFile('new_image.jpg', file.read(), content_type='multipart/form-data')

        data = {
            'image': uploaded_file,
            'houses': self.house.id,
        }

        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
        response = self.client.post(reverse('api:house_images-list'), data, format='multipart')
        response.render()

        self.assertEqual(status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response.status_code)
```

Comment: Same error. <Response status_code=400, "application/json">

Comment: Did you set your `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`?

Comment: Did you print out the response like `print(response.json())`, there you can see what's the error actually raising... Also, could you post the `models.py` for `House` and `HouseImage`?

Comment: In your `HouseImage` model, field_name is `houses` (which is a mandatory field, ie, NOT NULL), but in your test, its `house`. Maybe that's the error is about. Change `house` => `houses` in `data`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154842/discussion-between-sarit-and-zaidfazil).