# Django: Upload file via POST request

Tags: python, django, file, post, uploading

I'm trying to upload file via APIView, but I'm getting that exception: `{"exception": "ValidationException", "code": 401, "message": "You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream"}`
Here's my code:

API View:

```
class SetAvatarView(LoginRequiredAPIView):
    @csrf_exempt  # Does no affect to situation
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            request.account.update_avatar(request.FILES['file'])
        except ValidationException, e:
            return JsonResponse(e.to_dict(), status=400)
        return JsonResponse({}, 200)
```

`Account` model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=AVATARS_URL, default='default.jpg')
    ...
    def update_avatar(self, f):
        self.avatar = f
```

Test code for uploading file:

```
def test_set_avatar(self):
    url = "/account/avatar/set/"
    with open("test.jpg", "r") as fp:
        response = self.client.post(url, {'file': fp}, #content_type='multipart/form-data', # Getting 400 Bad Request if uncomment
                                    **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Token 0ff0884090**********8ef5387423bc24cd15e1'})
    print response.content
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

No additional middlewares in `settings.py`, and I tried to disable default middlewares, no result.

Comment: i think you need `fp.read()`

Comment: If send file like `{'file': fp.read()}` I receive `{"error": "HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type"}
`

Comment: And if send like that and add content-type: image/jpeg, so error is `Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

Comment: try to add `format='multipart'` from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27576436/8060120

Comment: `format='multipart` with content-type and fp.read() doesn't affect at all

Comment: did you try others answer in the link?

Comment: Maybe I found a solution, but there are strange exception
```
response = self.client.post(url,
                                        data=encode_multipart(BOUNDARY, {'file': fp}),
                                        **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Token 0ff08840935eb00fad198ef5387423bc24cd15e1'})
```
```
 line 197, in encode_multipart
    for (key, value) in data.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```
`data` is a dict(`{'file': fp }`) but there is an error saying that data has no "items" method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encode the file and decode in the view /account/avatar/set

```
import base64 
def test_set_avatar(self):
    url = "/account/avatar/set/"
    with open("test.jpg", "r") as fp:
    response = self.client.post(url, {'file': base64.b64encode(fp.read())}, #content_type='multipart/form-data', # Getting 400 Bad Request if uncomment
                                **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': 'Token 0ff0884090**********8ef5387423bc24cd15e1'})
    print response.content
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: But actually it does not solve the original problem. Yes, you can send file as base64-encoded string, but what if you're going to use this endpoint in HTML form or public API and want to just receive file?