# Request not sending file in django test

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I want to test a view that is suppose to receive files attached with the request.
my django test:

```py
TEST_DIR = "myapp/tests/test_data/"
file_name = "some_resume.pdf"
email_data = {
  "sender": "somedude@someprovidercom",
  "recipient": "someotherdude@someotherprovider.com",
  "subject": "New candidate",
  "stripped-html": "Check out this new candidate."
}

api = APIClient()

with open(FILE_DIR + file_name, "rb") as fp:
  response = api.post(
    "/api/v1.0/emails/receive/",
    data=email_data,
    files={"resume": fp},  # pass file handler open with byte mode
    format="multipart",  # use multipart format
  )
  print(response)


# test some stuff
```

the api response is correct: `<Response status_code=200, "application/json">`

but when I print the files attached to the request in the View I get nothing:

```py
print(request.FILES)
# <MultiValueDict: {}>
```

I checked everywhere and the format for my api request looks file.
Also, my view works fine when I test with shell sending request with with python `requests` library.
Am I missing anything? Could id be somehow related to my test environment or some obscure middlewares?

Comment: print response tu see more info, be care about email_data its on correct format

Comment: I wrote the payload content and the response data that I get, everything is normal

Comment: try it, will give u more info
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588644/how-can-i-see-the-entire-http-request-thats-being-sent-by-my-python-application

Comment: You're probably using DRF, so without seeing your view (e.g. to see if you specify any parsers (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser)), you might want to try and pass the `fp` in the `data=` argument (inside `email_data`). Here's some good discussion on the matter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24201676/how-can-i-test-binary-file-uploading-with-django-rest-frameworks-test-client/50648293