# Getting 415 code with django.test.Client's patch method

Tags: python, django

Edit: I've tried everything in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153048/django-rest-framework-http-put-failing-with-415-on-django-1-5) and it doesn't solve the issue. Meaning I tried I tried manually adding FormParser and MultiPartParser to DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES in settings, and I've tried changing django.test.TestCase to rest_framework.test.APITestCase. I still get the same error code.

When I send a PATCH request to my Django app running on localhost via the command line like so:

```
http -a <username>:<password> PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/ text="new text"
```

It works as expected and I get a 200 OK code back.

When I try to do the same thing in my unit test using the `django.test.Client.patch` method like this:

```
In [1]: from django.test import Client
In [2]: client = Client()
In [3]: client.login(username='<username>', password='<password>')
Out[3]: True
In [4]: client.patch('/post/1/', {'text': 'new text'})
Out[4]: <Response status_code=415, "application/json">
```

I get a 415 (Unsupported Media) response code. The `response.data` is `Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.'`

If I try adding the parameter `content-type='application/json'` to the `patch` method (I shouldn't have to do this because I'm able to send `GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE` requests using the `Client` class without providing that parameter) I get a 400 error code. and the `response.data` is `'JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)'`

As I said, when I use the class's `get`, `delete`, and `post` methods, the behavior is as expected.

Am I using the method properly? Is this a bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-rest-framework http put failing with 415 on django 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153048/django-rest-framework-http-put-failing-with-415-on-django-1-5)

Comment: @Linch that doesn't solve it.

Comment: Have you tried encoding the dictionary as json as the related question suggests, i.e. `client.patch('/post/1/', json.dumps({'text': 'new text'}), content_type="application/json")`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As far as I know, `httpie` sends a request with the content-type `application/json`.

So, try this:

```
import json 
data = json.dumps({'text': 'new text'})

client.patch('/post/1/', data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: This works for me too, but it's a bit manual as a global solution to have to dump data for every test and also specify `content_type` for every test. Is there a more global solution that you know of? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can set this globally in settings with `'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json'` as per docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#configuration

Comment: I have no clue why for POST you can miss content_type without getting a 415...

Answer (score 1):

As for why you need to add a `content_type` for `PATCH` (and `PUT`, `OPTIONS`, `DELETE`). It's because Django uses different defaults for `content_type`. For `post` it uses `multipart/form-data` while for the others it uses `application/octet-stream`. Not 100% sure why, but that explains the `POST/GET` succeeding