# Django REST framework RequestsClient content-type

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, http-headers, python-requests, content-type

First thanks for the great work, I love using Django REST framework to automate all the boilerplate of web API endpoints creation.

I ran into a problem when using the rest_framework.test.RequestsClient to test some API endpoints. I found the solution but now I am wondering how I could have found the solution faster.

**Here was the problem:** I tried to test a PUT API endpoint using the following piece of code (inspired by the requests doc to specify the content-type through custom headers: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#custom-headers):

```
from rest_framework.test import RequestsClient 
client = RequestsClient()
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = client.put(my_url, json.dumps(my_data), headers=self.headers)
```

And got a status **415** with the following detail:

`{'detail': 'Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.'}`

**Solution:** Hmm ok, seems the specified content-type was not taken into consideration. A search on google led me to this stackoverflow post specifying the content-type through the **content_type kwarg** of the put method: [django-rest-framework http put failing with 415 on django 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153048/django-rest-framework-http-put-failing-with-415-on-django-1-5)

`response = client.put(..., content_type='application/json')`

**Question:**

How could I have found faster that the supported way to specify the content-type was through the content_type kwarg and not through the headers kwarg? I checked the DRF source code here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/test.py and it seems that the DjangoTestAdapter would make it possible to specify the content-type through the headers kwarg:

```
69   if 'content-type' in request.headers:
70       kwargs['content_type'] = request.headers['content-type']
```

I am tired I might have missed something. Also I didn't dig deep into the DRF source code.

Thanks for any piece of information!

Answer (score 0):

I do this, but I dont know if this is correct form.

```
self.client = RequestsClient()
self.client.headers.update({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
response = self.client.post(f'{URL}', data=json.dumps(data_object))
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a client from DRF: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
client = APIClient()
client.post('/notes/', {'title': 'new idea'}, format='json')
```

Comment: This suggests an alternative solution which is different from requester's problem context.